# i18next.js not served on subpages

Tags: javascript, node.js, i18next

i am writing a node server with i18next.

on my main page (http://localhost:3000), the i18next.js gets served as expected.

on a subpage (http://localhost:3000/users/hans), however, it does not.

```
(404) GET http://localhost:3000/users/i18next/i18next.js 
frontend.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

i don't understand why.

app.js

```
//[...]
var app = express();


var user = require('./routes/users');  // USER ROUTE
var routes = require('./routes/index');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

i18n.serveClientScript(app).serveDynamicResources(app);
//[...]
```

frontend.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.i18n.init({
        debug: true,
        detectLngQS: 'lang',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        load: 'unspecific',
        lowerCaseLng: true,
        resGetPath: './locales/__lng__-__ns__.json',
    }, function() {
        $.t('markup.login');
        $('p, a, h1, label, button').i18n();
    });
    $('.langButton').on('click', function(event) {
        var setLangTo = $(event.target).attr('name');
        console.log(setLangTo);
        $.i18n.setLng(setLangTo, function() {
            $('p, a, h1, label, button').i18n();
        })
    })
});
```

as I understand it, the i18next.js should be automatically served to any request, independent from routes. i also don't know how to change the path to `/`, so that the js can be loaded normally...

am i missing something? wrong order (i tried reordering to no avail)? any settings i should have changed?

thanks for your help :)

#### additional info

i just noticed that this only happens on the user page (two sub-levels)
ONE sub-level (e.g. localhost:3000/training) works..... this is strange.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I feel ashamed now...

For anyone as stupid as me:

It has to be

```
script(src='/i18next/i18next.js', type='text/javascript')
```

instead of

```
script(src='i18next/i18next.js', type='text/javascript')
```